# Django Images In Media Not Displaying Despite Correct Settings

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to upload an image from a form and display it on another template, however the images in media cannot be found.

Model

```
class Upload(models.Model):
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
```

View

```
class HomePageView(CreateView):
    model = Upload
    form_class = UploadForm
    template_name = 'home.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('rank')

class RankView(ListView):
    model = Rank
    template_name = 'rank.html'
```

Settings

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Urls

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('avatars.urls')),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Upload Template

```
 <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {{ form.as_p }}
  <button type="submit">Upload Image</button>
</form>
```

Retrieving Image with

```
<img src="{{upload.image.url}}">
```

Form

```
class UploadForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Upload
    fields = ['image']
```

Inspecting the code in browser, the img url is 'unknown'

Edit: tried changing my view, it made no difference

```
def upload_file(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/rank')
else:
    form = UploadForm()
return render(request, 'home.html', {'form': form})
```

Comment: please send your form template(upload image)

Comment: added the form @hadi

Comment: html form template file

Comment: Upload template added

Comment: your form has not `action` attribute!

Comment: ok, what is type of `upload` (`<img src="{{upload.image.url}}">`)?

Comment: Form doesn't need an action, the files are being uploaded to media/images regardless

Comment: the final step, check your `Rank` model. maybe `upload.image.image.url` or `rank.image.image.url` or `rank.image.url` is required

Comment: Unfortunately none of these work

Comment: How `Rank` and `Upload` are related in `models.py`? Mostly you will need something like this: `<img src="{{rank.upload.image.url}}">`

Comment: They have no relation, should Rank and Upload be related?

Answer (score 0):

try using render insted of template_name and form does not have action attribute

return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

[https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/intro/#handling-forms-with-class-based-views][1]

Comment: I updated it accordingly, the same thing is still happening

Comment: have u installed pillow? and try to print the url in template to see that is it comming in template ? watch it in the djanog admin is it storing it properly ? what about action attribute?

Comment: Checked the django admin, all the images are being stored correctly. I can also access them at http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/images/imagename

Answer (score 0):

i think in the you should remove the model from the create view because you are using the form_class , try it

```
class HomePageView(CreateView):
    form_class = UploadForm
    template_name = 'home.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('rank')
```

hope it works